# problemas con boton submit

Tags: php, html5, wordpress, html-select

tengo este "form" pero no hace el efecto del submit el cual quiero enviar estos datos a un ajax realmente el ajax es demaciado simple pero realmente no se mete ni a la funcion alguien tiene idea de lo que pueda ser, muestro el html pienso que el problema esta aqui.

```html
<div class="buscar">
    <div class="buscars">
    <form id= "form_filtroscajas" method="post">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Servicio</label>
                <select id="servicio" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">1</option>    
                </select>       
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Productos</label>
                <select id="producto" class="form-control">
                        <option value="2">2</option>    
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ubicación</label>
                <select id="estado" class="form-control">   
                        <option value="3">3</option>      
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <div class="form-group"><br>
                <p><a type="submit" class="btn btn-verde btn-block mt5">FILTRAR</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

este es mi archivo js es un simple ajax que recoge los datos del formulario.lo cual no esta compuesto por muchas cosas.

```
 jQuery("#form_filtroscajas").submit(function( e ) {
 var datastring = jQuery(this).serialize();
 jQuery.ajax({
            url: "aqui pongo una url de un archivo php que uso",
            data: datastring, 
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(data){             
                if(data == "success"){
                    alert("esta funcionando");
                    location.reload();
                    
                }else{
                    // alert(data);
                    alert("Un error sucedió");
                }
                
                return false;
            },
            error: function( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                return;
            } });
            e.preventDefault();
         });
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está el código JS con la petición Ajax? Pon al menos un `alert` para verificar si está entrando en el código JS.

Comment: Pues a simple vista parece que no hace el submit, porque tienes un `<a>` en lugar de un `<button>`, igualmente coloca el resto de código para ver si ocurre algo más en el JS. Saludos.

Comment: listo amigos muchas gracias por responder la verdad he actualizado el codigo y con ese js funciona normalmente suelo ponerlo asi

Comment: Como ya te dijeron el problema es que usas un enlace en lugar de un botón,, los enlaces carecen de la propiedad type, modifica eso y veras como te funciona al 100

Comment: muchísimas gracias la verdad me funciono lo de la etiquetas

Answer (score 0):

Como te mencione en los comentarios, solamente es necesario cambiar el `<a>` por `<button>`, de esta forma debería funcionar.

```js
jQuery("#form_filtroscajas").submit(function( e ) {
             e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Submit realizado ;)");
                    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buscar">
    <div class="buscars">
    <form id= "form_filtroscajas" method="post">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Servicio</label>
                <select id="servicio" class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">1</option>    
                </select>       
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Productos</label>
                <select id="producto" class="form-control">
                        <option value="2">2</option>    
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
          <div class="form-group">
                <label>Ubicación</label>
                <select id="estado" class="form-control">   
                        <option value="3">3</option>      
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <div class="form-group"><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">FILTRAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```